# Keras gives : ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I have used mobilenet model to train my dataset and saved the model using `model.save('mobilenet2.h5')`. Now I am trying on Google Colab to load this model using `model_new = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/mobilenet2.h5')`  but it is showing me error of `ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer`. I checked online and tried loading model using `model_new = tf.keras.models.load_model(('/content/drive/MyDrive/mobilenet2.h5'), custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})` but then it shows me error of `ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 2 layers into a model with 1 layers.`. I tried loading model on local machine but it again shows the first error. How does it occuring and what should I do to solve it?

**Loading Model by using**

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/mobilenet2.h5')
```

Traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-046714005579> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow_hub as hub
----> 2 model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/mobilenet2.h5')

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    294   cls = get_registered_object(class_name, custom_objects, module_objects)
    295   if cls is None:
--> 296     raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
    297 
    298   cls_config = config['config']

ValueError: Unknown layer: KerasLayer
```

**Loading Model using**

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(('/content/drive/MyDrive/mobilenet2.h5'), custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})
```

Traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7d3998cd0bd9> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow_hub as hub
----> 2 model = tf.keras.models.load_model(('/content/drive/MyDrive/mobilenet2.h5'), custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers)
    686                      'containing ' + str(len(layer_names)) +
    687                      ' layers into a model with ' + str(len(filtered_layers)) +
--> 688                      ' layers.')
    689 
    690   # We batch weight value assignments in a single backend call

ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 2 layers into a model with 1 layers.
```

**Model Summary**

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
keras_layer_2 (KerasLayer)   (None, 1280)              2257984   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 374)               479094    
=================================================================
Total params: 2,737,078
Trainable params: 479,094
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
```

Comment: Can you add the model.summary() before saving the model? This will hlep.

Comment: @J369 Yes. I have added the summary.

Comment: @Aanand Rathore, Can you standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Did you solve it?